Ideal way to save edits to a Kubernetes Deployment/StatefulSet
I edited a deployment and a stateful set of a Helm chart so that it mounts a specific persistent volume to the pod container deployed to a local cluster. The Helm chart is installed via Helm install from a remote repository.
What is the best way to save the adjusted manifest so that I can deploy the updated deployment/sts to a new cluster? Can I add the volume mount to the Helm chart locally somehow and get it installed from there the next time? Should I have my own local Helm repo?
The changed part was not in the original chart attributes that get overriden by values.yaml or --set.

Check the helm chart's (default) values; perhaps maintainers of the helm chart thought about your use case.

You can show the differences between your cluster state and the installed Helm release with:
helm get manifest <release_name> |  kubectl diff -f -

You can then compare the differences with the Helm chart stored in your Git repository and incorporate the necessary changes.
About your second question, you don't have to install an Helm local repository, you can install an Helm chart from a local Helm package file (tar.gz).
